# How to print bufferedImage on pdf

Tags: java, swing, pdf, graphics, itext

I am working on pdf report application. Using

itext 5.3.3.jar
jdk 1.6

I am trying to print JTable on the pdf. I got the JTable image correctly, but unable to get the image on pdf. Is their anyway I can print the BufferedImage on the pdf. I used the below code for it:-

Trying to write a bufferedImage on pdf if possible.

```
private static void print(BufferedImage bi,JTable table) { 
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate()); 
    try { 
      PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("F:/jTable.pdf")); 

      document.open(); 
      PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); 
      PdfTemplate pdfTemplate = cb.createTemplate(table.getWidth(), table.getHeight()); 
      Image image = Image.getInstance(bi , null); 
      image.scaleToFit(table.getWidth(), table.getHeight()); 
      table.addNotify();
      table.validate();
      Graphics2D g2 = pdfTemplate.createGraphics(table.getWidth(), table.getHeight()); 
      table.print(g2);
      pdfTemplate.addImage(image); 
      /*g2.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
      g2.drawRect(x-2, y-2, table.getWidth()+2, table.getHeight()+2);*/ 
      //table.print(g2); 

      cb.addTemplate(pdfTemplate, 0,20); 



    } catch (Exception e) { 
      System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    } 
    document.close(); 
  }
```

But it shows me something like below:-

The image must have absolute positioning.
Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced save/restore state operators.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.sanityCheck(PdfContentByte.java:3083)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.toPdf(PdfContentByte.java:248)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfFormXObject.(PdfFormXObject.java:88)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate.getFormXObject(PdfTemplate.java:247)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addXFormsToBody(PdfWriter.java:1293)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addSharedObjectsToBody(PdfWriter.java:1304)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1209)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:768)
    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:398)
    at com.swing.data.TableImage.print(TableImage.java:102)
    at com.swing.data.TableImage.main(TableImage.java:52)

Following is the code for testing:-

```
package com.swing.data;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;



class TableImage {
    BufferedImage bi = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Hari", new Integer(23), new Double(78.23), (true)},
            {"James", new Integer(23), new Double(47.64), (false)},
            {"Sally", new Integer(22), new Double(84.81), (true)}
        };
        String[] columns = {"Name", "Age", "GPA", "Pass"};
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
        JTableHeader h = table.getTableHeader();
        int x = table.getWidth();
        int y = table.getHeight();
        table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,0));
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ColumnAlignmentRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)));
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                x, y, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        table.paint(g2);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
        print(bi,table);
        //createPdf(true,table);
    }
   private static void print(BufferedImage bi,JTable table) { 
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate()); 
        try { 
          PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("F:/jTable.pdf")); 

          document.open(); 
          PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); 
          PdfTemplate pdfTemplate = cb.createTemplate(table.getWidth(), table.getHeight()); 
          Image image = Image.getInstance(bi , null); 
          image.scaleToFit(table.getWidth(), table.getHeight()); 
          table.addNotify();
          table.validate();
          Graphics2D g2 = pdfTemplate.createGraphics(table.getWidth(), table.getHeight()); 
          table.print(g2);
          pdfTemplate.addImage(image); 
          /*g2.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
          g2.drawRect(x-2, y-2, table.getWidth()+2, table.getHeight()+2);*/ 
          //table.print(g2); 

          cb.addTemplate(pdfTemplate, 0,20); 



        } catch (Exception e) { 
          System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
        } 
        document.close(); 
      } 
     private TableImage() {
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can simply create [com.itextpdf.text.Image](https://www.itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText5/5.5.13/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html) from [java.awt.image.BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and then render it using standard iText methods:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;

BufferedImage bufferedImage = ...
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", baos);
Image iTextImage = Image.getInstance(baos.toByteArray());
```

See [iText Image Examples](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-5-legacy/adding-image-existing-file) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                               new FileOutputStream("Image.pdf"));
        document.open();

        PdfContentByte pdfCB = new PdfContentByte(writer);
        Image image = Image.getInstance(pdfCB, bufferedImage, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://stderr.org/doc/libitext-java-doc/www/tutorial/ch10.html).  Seems to explain how to do Absolute Positioning.  I would guess that you would need to do that.

Comment: Internet Archive has cached it. http://web.archive.org/web/20141222182518/http://stderr.org/doc/libitext-java-doc/www/tutorial/ch10.html